# how to make my python-flask website available 24*7 using nginx and gunicorn

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

How to configure gunicorn to make sure my python-flask website is available 24*7 ?
The issue I am facing is: As soon I kill my terminal window, the website is no more reachable.

I am using rhel7.6 to host a website using python-flask.
I have configured nginx as the web server and gunicorn as the application server.

.
I will really appreciate if some one can help me in using/configuring gunicorn to make sure my website is available 24*7.

Please have some of my code as below:

```
[root@syed-dashboard-4 ~]# pwd
/root
[root@syed-dashboard-4 ~]#
[root@syed-dashboard-4 ~]# cat hello.py
#!/usr/bin/python

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
        return "Hello magentabox!"

#if __name__ == "__main__":
#        app.run(host='10.145.29.23',port=5000)

[root@syed-dashboard-4 ~]#
[root@syed-dashboard-4 ~]# gunicorn hello:app
[2019-07-17 10:34:11 +0000] [9346] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2019-07-17 10:34:11 +0000] [9346] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (9346)
[2019-07-17 10:34:11 +0000] [9346] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2019-07-17 10:34:11 +0000] [9351] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9351
```

I am pretty new to web development and as I mentioned as soon I close the terminal, the website is no more reachable. I can share the nginx configuration logs as well if that helps fixing my issue.
Thanks much.

Comment: You want to look into WSGI applications. I have an example on github - https://github.com/bascoe10/python-flask-apache-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the supervisor. This is the professional way to run your server for 24*7.
Please add below file in your supervisor config to run.

```
[program:your_project_name]
command=/home/virtualenvpath/your_env/bin/gunicorn --log-level debug run_apiengine:main_app --bind 0.0.0.0:5006 --workers 5 --worker-class gevent
stdout_logfile=/home/your_path_to_log/supervisor_stdout.log
stderr_logfile=/home/your_path_to_log/supervisor_stderr.log
user=your_user
autostart=true
autorestart=true
environment=PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/home/path_to_your_project";OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT='1';
```

Configure this in supervisor it will run for 24*7. And whenever your machine restarts it will auto start.

Comment: Thanks much Prashant.
I followed the above step you suggested. It intermittently breaks and it displays 
"[CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT". 
I tried making the following changes to the above file ( one by one ) but none helped.
1)
 proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
 proxy_read_timeout 300s;

2) 
     fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
     proxy_read_timeout 300;

3) The number of processors on my virtual machine are 8, so I increased worker_processes  to 8, worker_connections to 2048 and keepalive_timeout  300seconds.

I am using rhel7.

Comment: Thanks much,
I made some further changes. The issue is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you can start your app in a [tmux](https://tmuxcheatsheet.com/) session that you detach once you started your server.

```sh
# Create a new tmux session
tmux new -s server

# Start your gunicorn server
cd /path/to/app
gunicorn hello:app

# Detach the current tmux session using Ctrl - B + D
```

You can close your terminal and your server will still be running.

Comment: Hi Francois,
I appreciate your prompt response. Currently I am hosting the website using nohup already.
But I am looking forward to learn a professional way of doing it. I would like to learn how the actual production websites are hosted.
Thanks

Comment: I am running my flask app as systemd service. Not sure if it's professional way, but it works.